# Flutter - Class 'QuerySnapshot' has no instance method 'document'

Tags: flutter, snapshot, stream-builder

I am getting the following error:

> ════════ Exception caught by widgets library
>   ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════
>
> The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building
>   StreamBuilder(dirty, state:
>   _StreamBuilderBaseState>#f469b): Class 'QuerySnapshot' has no
>   instance method 'document'. Receiver: Instance of 'QuerySnapshot'
>   Tried calling: document("+918130343322")

```
body:
  StreamBuilder(
      stream: Firestore.instance.collection('users').snapshots(),
      builder: (context, snapshot){
        if(!snapshot.hasData) return Text('Loading data.....');
        return
            Center(child: Text(snapshot.data.document(_myMobile)["Name"]),);
```

`_mymobile` is the document ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this code returns you a list `snapshot.data.documents` not a document

if you want to do this you need try do this

```
final specificDocument = snapshot.data.documents.where((f) {
     return f.documentID == _myMobile;
}).toList();
```